# Excel Automation Error on half of code executions

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that goes through a list where each line tells it to do something to a specified file. To cut down on number of Save-Close-Open operations, my list is sorted by file path (each file typically appears in several lines and every line works on a different worksheet in that file). The below code handles file manipulation.

```
mypath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Range("B" & row).Value

If mywbk Is Nothing Then
    Set mywbk = Workbooks.Open(mypath)
Else
    If mywbk.FullName = mypath Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        mywbk.Save
        mywbk.Close
        Set mywbk = Workbooks.Open(mypath)
    End If
End If
```

`mywbk` is `Workbook`, `mypath` is `String`. What I expect the code to do is to check if anything is stored currently in mywbk, if nothing, set it to file I currently want to work on, if something already is there, I want to check if I still want to work on this file (and then nothing needs to happen), or if I have to change the file (so I save and close the previous one and open the new one).

The problem I have is run-time error `'-2147221080 (800401a8)'` which happens right on the first time I go through this part of code, but only every second run of the macro - if I click `End` on error screen and run once more, everything works as expected. Then on next run I get the error again and so on. What is the reason for this behaviour and is there any way to fix it?

Edit - clarifications after comments:

`mywbk` is Private variable

The error happens on `If mywbk.FullName = mypath Then`, the value when the error happens is `<Automation error>`

Comment: If `mywbk` is public variable, make sure to have `Set mywkb = Nothing` at the end of your code.

Comment: what's the line erroring out? what's the value of `mywbk.Name` right before erroring out?

Comment: edited to answer both comments

Comment: have you got any `On Error resume Next` or `ON Error GoTo someLabel` statement ruling before that piece of code?

Comment: no, I have no error handling at all in this code

Comment: and _"the value when the error happens is"_...?

Comment: corrected, thanks, SO interpreted the value as some code

Comment: The error might as well be with `mypath`. Put a break point there and single step through it to check whether the error actually occurs at `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Range("B" & row).Value`

Comment: I was asking for `mywbk.Name` right before erroring out